# php preg_replace adding quotes and not matching after the quote

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have a php function that highlights text that has been searched for, it works, until you start searching with quotes, and then it adds slashes, but by doing so, it stops it from matching the rest of the string after the slash.

for example:

what I want it to do:

Search term: `Ronnie's h`

result: **Ronnie's h**

actual results:

**Ronnie**'s h

```
function highlight($needle, $haystack)
{
    $result =  preg_replace("/(".preg_quote($needle, "/").")/i", "<strong>$1</strong>", $haystack);
    return $result;
}


echo highlight("ronnie's h", "ronnie's home");
```

Comment: It seems to be working fine http://codepad.org/vooGfwzg

Comment: Check with `<strong style="color:#800;">`. Maybe the `h` is not being visibly bold in the browser.

Comment: Yeah, even doing the color thing, none of the text gets bolded after putting a `'` in the search. But I can't figure out why it worked for you on codepad. :\

Comment: Do `var_dump($needle, $haystack);` inside the function in your real code and check if single quotes are present.

Comment: yes it has the single quote `string(10) "Liam o'con" string(18) "Liam O'Connor" `

Comment: There are 18 letters in `string(18)`. So it could be `Liam O&#039;Connor`. But in that case the regex shouldn't match. Weird.

Comment: Well, there are 18 letters in the full name (the haystack), and 10 letters in the search (the needle), as they should be. either way.. this doesn't make any sense as to why it's not working.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't try this sooner... `$needle = str_replace("'", "&#039;", $needle);` fixed it..so ultimately, htmlspecialchars is the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using `preg_replace` for this? It'd be much easier as:

```
function highlight($needle,$haystack) {
    return str_replace($needle,"<strong>".$needle."</strong>",$haystack);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, and well two thing, firstly, the issue I'm having is still present when I do it like that, and secondly, this one is case sensitive.

Comment: Ah, yes, case. That's why. Okay, well I'm not sure why the problem would still be happening - let's try getting that fixed before worrying about case. Can you try View Source and see what the generated HTML is?